# IE 11/Edge respects page-break-* in different ways from other browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, page-break

I've noticed that if I put `page-break-before: always` or `page-break-after: always` in IE11/Edge, it gives me a blank page at the front or end of the printable document, respectively.  Firefox and Chrome act differently: If I put a `page-break-before: always` on something on the first page, it doesn't create a blank page in front.  If I put `page-break-after: always` on the last page, it doesn't put a blank page at the end.  Is there any trick to getting IE to act like the others (or getting the others to act like IE)?

Here's some HTML to reproduce this:

```
<html><body>
<p style="page-break-before: always">Page break before!</p>
</body></html>
```

Just open it up in IE and look at the print preview.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with multiple browsers and check the result that Edge and IE adds a new page whereas other browsers are not adding a new page.

It depends on each browser and each browser will produce a different output with similar code.

I can see that your requirement is to produce a similar output with all the browsers.

For that, You can try to use line of code below.

```html
<BR style="page-break-before:always">
```

Then try to make a test with Edge or IE.

You can notice that it is not adding a blank page.

[image]

By this way you can try to achieve similar output in multiple browsers.